# Exclude Eclipse's hidden '.settings' directory from commits when using TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using the TortoiseSVN client and Eclipse. When I attempt to commit an Eclipse project, TortoiseSVN displays a `.settings` directory in the file list and says that it is un-versioned. The `.settings' directory seems to be where Eclipse keeps all of its settings for a project.

Is there a way to exclude this directory so that it is completely ignored by TortoiseSVN for this and any other Eclipse projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to ignore this folder globally, you should use…a global ignore!

Take a look at the file

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\config
```

and uncomment the `global-ignores` line and add `.settings` to it.

---

**Sample**

Sample full path for the file `config`:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\pmn\Application Data\Subversion\config
```

Sample new content of the `global-ignores` line:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store .settings
```

Comment: Does TortoiseSVN actually use that file? In one instance at least, it seems it is using the registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany\global-ignores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369680/where-does-tortoisesvn-store-its-settings-e-g-global-ignore-pattern/9196267#9196267) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude directories like this by right clicking on them in Windows and going to TortoiseSVN/"Delete and add to ignore list" and then specifying it in the sub-menu:

[image]

This is really easy to do, I have to do it quite often.

Comment: Does this actually delete the local directory?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It deletes it from svn, not from the file system.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify resources to ignore under Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Ignored resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse you might want to try out subClipse, it's a free subversion plugin for eclipse and it will allow you to exclude the .setings folder. See [this link](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

However, are you sure you don't want these to be comitted? Since your project is build in Eclipse, one could say that the setings are a part of your project.

Personally I like to commit these files as they allow me to keep the same settings for every project on every location and for every developer.

Comment: Well due to the nature of SVN and it's ability to allow multiple people to work on a single project, committing a single users Eclipse `.settings` directory would break other users Eclipse configuration when they do an update.

Comment: It will make sure that they are working in the same environment. It does not break their Eclipse configuration as it is set for each project. It depends on what you want as I said in my answer.