# Where does TortoiseSVN store its settings (for example, Global Ignore Pattern)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, settings

When setting up an instance of the excellent [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/), I find myself repeating its settings, for example, 'default checkout folder' and 'global ignore pattern' (as well as many others such as the linked tools). This is a pain. Where is the latter stored?

I've found the former around the registry key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN]`, but 'global ignore pattern' is missing. A text search of the user tree doesn't find it either. Where is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Readme of Subversion, which seems to be installed with TortoiseSVN anyway:

> File locations
>
> ==============
>
> Typically, Subversion uses two config directories, one for site-wide
>   configuration,
>
> Unix:
>
> ```
> /etc/subversion/servers
> /etc/subversion/config
> /etc/subversion/hairstyles
> ```
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
> %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\servers
> %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\config
> %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Subversion\hairstyles
> REGISTRY:HKLM\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Servers
> REGISTRY:HKLM\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config
> REGISTRY:HKLM\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Hairstyles
> ```
>
> and one for per-user configuration:
>
> Unix:
>
> ```
> ~/.subversion/servers
> ~/.subversion/config
> ~/.subversion/hairstyles
> ```
>
> Windows:
>
> ```
> %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers
> %APPDATA%\Subversion\config
> %APPDATA%\Subversion\hairstyles
> REGISTRY:HKCU\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Servers
> REGISTRY:HKCU\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config
> REGISTRY:HKCU\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Hairstyles
> ```

Some of the settings are actually Subversion settings and not TortoiseSVN settings, so this may be the right place to look.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseSVN` seems to contain paths to the TortoiseSVN tools.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN` has a lot more tools though.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming by 'global ignore pattern' you mean the setting 'global-ignores', spying using [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) while setting it from the user interface (right click in a Windows Explorer window/TortoiseSVN/Settings) reveals that it is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany`:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany]
"global-ignores"="*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store *.xy9"
"use-commit-times"="no"
```

This was tested with TortoiseSVN 1.6.12 (build 20536, 2010-11-24), Subversion 1.6.15.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the [TortoiseSVN's Settings](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) dialogue, in section *General*, you'll find:

1. *global ignore pattern:* and a corresponding edit line
2. the label *Subversion configuration file:* and an [Edit] button behind it, which opens (as for version 1.9.5) the file `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` in your preferred text editor.

I suggest using the GUI integrated into TortoiseSVN as the intended (and that's why most reliable) way.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Subversion-based Windows 7 SVN clients (including [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN)) will look in the following places in the order shown for configuration settings:

1. The system-wide Registry values - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion key
2. The system-wide INI files -  I don't think this is used for Windows 7
3. The per-user Registry values - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion key
4. The per-user INI files - %home%\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config (a.k.a. %APPDATA%\Subversion\config)
5. Command-line options

If a value is in more than one place the last occurence will take precedence.