# Is there a way to set up LabVIEW Compare option with TortoiseSVN programmatically?

Tags: tortoisesvn, labview

I would like to setup LabVIEW Compare option with Tortoise SVN.

I have already followed these steps in the link below to manually set things up 
https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Source-Code-Control-Using-TortoiseSVN-Subversion-with-LabVIEW/ta-p/3510829

But I would like to do the same programmatically(maybe using LabVIEW) so that I will be able to automate this process in other users PC.

Comment: Take another look on the task - configure Tortoise SVN once, and then copy and distribute configuration files (location you could find here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6369824/6917446) to other PCs. It is more efficient, then automate configuration process.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly this purpose, I created a file `LabviewCompare.reg` file with this content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\DiffTools]
".vi"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\LabVIEW Compare\\LVCompare.exe\" %mine %base"
".ctl"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\LabVIEW Compare\\LVCompare.exe\" %mine %base"
".vit"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\LabVIEW Compare\\LVCompare.exe\" %mine %base"
".ctt"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\National Instruments\\Shared\\LabVIEW Compare\\LVCompare.exe\" %mine %base"
```

You might add this options behind the `%base` if you want to tweak the compare behavior:

- `-noattr`: Do not compare VI attributes.
- `-nofp`: Do not compare the front panels.
- `-nofppos`: Do not compare the size or position of front panel objects.
- `-nobd`: Do not compare the block diagrams.
- `-nobdcosm`: Do not compare the appearance of block diagram objects.
- `-nobdpos`: Do not compare the size or position of block diagram objects.

Double-click this file, say *yes* to add it to the registry, and you're done. 
It is really nice that this works on the fly: When you want to do a diff during an SVN operation and notice that yo haven't configured Tortoise yet, just load the registry file, and try to do the diff again - it works without canceling/closing the SVN task.

Of course, you can add the registry keys with LabVIEWs registry functions, but I'd suggest to run `regedit /S LabviewCompare.reg` on to command line. This is also easier to implement in LabVIEW.